# The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

Tags: cmake

I am new in Cmake thats why I will write story detailed.

I trying to build one lib under windows and that lib depends on other lib. (`libmatroska` depends on `libebml`) [source libmatroska](https://github.com/Matroska-Org/libmatroska) and [source libebml](https://github.com/Matroska-Org/libebml)
Fortunately both libs can be build with cmake.

I built `libebml` successfuly with cmake. And also built binaries using VS studio.

Then I tried to deal with `libmatroska`:
During first try I got:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Ebml" (requested
version 1.3.5) with any of the following names:

  EbmlConfig.cmake
  ebml-config.cmake
```

at `libebml` sources I found `EbmlConfig.cmake`.
I Type `export Ebml_DIR=D:/work/mkv/libebml` and try again.
On second run I got:

```
Could not find a configuration file for package "Ebml" that is compatible
with requested version "1.3.5".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

  D:/work/mkv/libebml/EbmlConfig.cmake, version: unknown
```

And after few hours I am still stuck on it.

I can't understand root of this error.
Is it something wrong with  `EbmlConfig.cmake`?
... or maybe I specified path to wrong `*.cmake` file?
... or I need to install `libebml` some how before handling `libmatroska`?
I will be happy for any clue.

UPDATE:
Here `EbmlConfig.cmake` context:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/EbmlTargets.cmake)
```

Where `EbmlTargets.cmake` is file generated while `Ebml` compilation.
I tried to change path inside `EbmlConfig.cmake` to global path. But got same error.
Also when I delete context of `EbmlConfig.cmake` I still have same error.
It looks like "default error when something goes wrong"

Comment: "at `libebml` **sources** I found `EbmlConfig.cmake`." - No, you should search that file under **installation** directory.

Comment: As far as I understand in this particular case this file refers to another `*.cmake` file (file in installation directory).

Comment: Yes, this file refers to `EbmlTargets.cmake` file in installation directory. But this "reference" is done via *relative* path (variable `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` refers to the directory with the current script), that is why location of `EbmlTargets.cmake` is important.

Comment: Ok. I understand your point. But how I can I fix it properly?

Comment: You need to **install** `libebml`, and hint with `Ebml_DIR` variable (or by other means) to the **install** path, not to the *source* one.

Comment: I understand that installation is good option. But have no idea how to perform it.  
I can't do something like `sudo make install` under windows

Comment: If you build the project under Visual Studio, use `INSTALL` target for install the project.